Raydium: Error processing Instruction 5: custom program error: 0x1000694
If you are trying to use https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/utilsCreateMarket.ts and faced an error in the second instruction such as
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 5: custom program error: 0x1000694

then this question is for you

Assumption: you want to do this in Devnet
Pre-requisites:
Make sure you in config.ts, you have made the following changes:
export const PROGRAMIDS = DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID;
export const addLookupTableInfo = undefined // only mainnet. other = undefined

Then, in src/utilsCreateMarket.ts, add the following setComputeUnitPrice line before the return statement
  createMarketInstruments.innerTransactions[1].instructions.push(ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({microLamports: 1_000_000 }))

// also add the skipPreflight true param
return { txids: await buildAndSendTx(createMarketInstruments.innerTransactions, { skipPreflight: true }) }


But if you try this you will run into an error because the transaction is now too big, so you need to create an Address Lookup Table
After you create one, make the following changes in util.ts, specifically, in buildAndSendTx
  const lookupTableAddress = new PublicKey("<LOOKUP_TABLE_ADDRESS>"); // add this line
  const lookupTableAccount = (
    await connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress)
  ).value; // add this line
  
  const willSendTx = await buildSimpleTransaction({
    connection,
    makeTxVersion,
    payer: wallet.publicKey,
    innerTransactions: innerSimpleV0Transaction,
    addLookupTableInfo: {
      '<LOOKUP_TABLE_ADDRESS>': lookupTableAccount!
    }, // modify this line
  })

replacing <LOOKUP_TABLE_ADDRESS> with the address of the Address Lookup Table you have created.
Then, re-run. Note that transaction success could still be intermittent and you might need to try more than once.
All the best.
